# GDB doesn't step into a function when use command "s"

Tags: c, linux, macos, debugging, gdb

I have a problem with GDB. When I use "s" to step into a function called from the `main` function, GDB jumps to another function without showing me the function that I need.

To be clear, I use step here:

In file *main.c*:

```
short c = get(a, b);
```

Now get has a 36 lines code and at line 27 it calls an other function "swap" here:

In file *get.s*:

```
call _swap;
```

When I use step (s) with GDB on "get", it jumps all of the *get* function and it shows me the *_swap* function.
These are three different files: *main.c*, *get.s*, and *swap.c compiled in this way:

```
gcc -g -m32 main.c swap.c get.s -o IA-main
```

-m32 because *get.s* is IA-32 assembly. Why does it jump the "get" function and show me only "_swap"?

I work on [Mac OS X v10.12.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) (Sierra), so GDB is a little annoying.

Comment: `step` jumps to the next source line. gdb probably doesn't consider assembly to be source.

Comment: Try using "stepi" to go through assembly.

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 9):

From *[Continuing and Stepping](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html)* (emphasis mine)

> *step*
>
> Continue running your program until control reaches a different source line, then stop it and return control to GDB. This command is abbreviated s.
>
> Warning: **If you use the step command while control is within a function that was compiled without debugging information, execution proceeds until control reaches a function that does have debugging information.** Likewise, it will not step into a function which is compiled without debugging information. **To step through functions without debugging information, use the stepi command**, described below.

You can use the `stepi` command instead:

> *stepi*
>
> *stepi arg*
>
> *si*
>
> Execute one machine instruction, then stop and return to the debugger.
>
> It is often useful to do ‘display/i $pc’ when stepping by machine instructions. This makes GDB automatically display the next instruction to be executed, each time your program stops. See Automatic Display.
>
> An argument is a repeat count, as in step.

Comment: It doesn't work as in it does that same thing as step? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it does the same thing of step, it jumps the get function until swap.

Comment: this is the output when I use stepi,I changed something now it see the function get but doesn't show me what's happening     [ (gdb) stepi
10  short c= get(a,b);
(gdb) 
0x00001eb5 10  short c= get(a,b); ]

Comment: When I type "info locals" while gdb is in get it says :"No symbol table info available."